# How to access a homekit-accessory from raspberry pi 3

Tags: bluetooth, home-automation

Maybe I realize in a second how stupid this question is...sorry in advance I am a bloody raspberry-novice.

I have a raspberry pi [(3B+)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/) and an [Eve Degree](https://www.evehome.com/en/eve-degree). I would like to connect the Degree to the rapsberry so that I can read out the measurements of the Degree.

Maybe this use case is not so common, but it all my google-searches returned homebridge related answers which (seems to) solve the opposite problem.

Is there a way run a (e.g. python) script on the raspberry which collects data from homekit accessories via Bluetooth? And if "yes" how does it work?

Comment: How is the connection to the Degree? Wifi, ethernet cable, USB, proprietary?

Comment: My understanding was that all homekit accessories have a bluetooth connection to their homekit hub. Was that wrong?

Comment: I would not bet on this.